# Create and include new file into python package

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to use version for my package base on `git describe` command. For this, I created `setup.py` with function `get_version()`. This function retrieves version from `.version` file if it exists, else computes new package version and writes it to a new `.version` file. However, when I call `python setup.py sdist`, `.version` is not copying inside `.tar` archive. This causes error when I'm trying to install package from PyPi repo. How to properly include my `.version` file "on the fly" into package?

`setup.py`:

```py
import pathlib
from subprocess import check_output
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


_VERSION_FILE = pathlib.Path(".version")  # Add it to .gitignore!
_GIT_COMMAND = "git describe --tags --long --dirty"
_VERSION_FORMAT = "{tag}.dev{commit_count}+{commit_hash}"


def get_version() -> str:
    """ Return version from git, write commit to file
    """
    if _VERSION_FILE.is_file():
        with _VERSION_FILE.open() as f:
            return f.readline().strip()
    output = check_output(_GIT_COMMAND.split()).decode("utf-8").strip().split("-")

    tag, count, commit = output[:3]
    dirty = len(output) == 4

    if count == "0" and not dirty:
        return tag

    version = _VERSION_FORMAT.format(tag=tag, commit_count=count, commit_hash=commit)

    with _VERSION_FILE.open("w") as f:
        print(version, file=f, end="")

    return version


_version = get_version()

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    package_data={
        "": [str(_VERSION_FILE)]
    },
    version=_version,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a file called `MANIFEST.in` in the same directory as `setup.py` with `include .version` inside, this should get the file picked up.

Comment: ```[00:01:03][Step 2/2] reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
[00:01:03][Step 2/2]   normalized_version,
[00:01:03][Step 2/2] writing manifest file 'mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[00:01:03][Step 2/2] warning: no files found matching '.version'
```
TravisCI does not see this file

Comment: This feels like it might be a separate problem. If you run locally, rather than with travis, does it work for you? I was able to get your setup.py to package to correct detect the .version file and include it in the tar file. Is this the case where you start without a .version file perhaps? If so could you try creating a dummy one and checking that part works for you. If it does then I can try and help with the no-.version file part

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake in `setup.py`. I forgot to add file dumping in `if count == "0" and not dirty:`. Now it works with `MANIFEST.in`.